# Can't set default screen with react native navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm trying to build an app, but I can't figure out how to have a screen by default.

This is my App.js:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Welcome' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name='Welcome' component={Welcome} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

But it's always the 'Login' page shown... But why?

Answer (score 0):

1. It should works correclty but if it doesnt you can reorder screens on top of each other. first screen will be default screen.

```js
<NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Welcome' component={Welcome} /> {/* <- default screen */}
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

2. Or update `React Navigation` to lastest version which is `6.x` and try again.